# Remove spaces from a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, whitespace

```
NSString *s = @"0800 444 333";
```

As you can see, this string has 2 white-spaces in the middle.
My questions is, how do I get rid of them so the string can become:

```
s = @"0800444333"
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This can be accomplished with simple string formatting. Here's an example:

```
NSString *s = @"0800 444 333";
NSString *secondString = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

See the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a) for more details and options.

To further simplify, this line can also be written like this:

```
NSString *s = [@"0800 444 333" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 13):

if You want to remove white spaces at start and end the you use`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]`string method.

For eg.

```
NSString *s = @"0800 444 333";
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

And for removing all spaces  answer by @NSPostWhenIdle is enough.

Comment: Not working on iOS 16.2 for some reason. I still get the output of ```0800 444 333```.

Comment: this will remove white space from the start and end of a string, not from the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but replacing @" " doesn't work in my case. The solution is easy, just write space as unicode character:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *s = @"0800 444 333";
NSString *secondString = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

See the `NSString` [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring) for more details and options.

To further simplify, this line can also be written like this:

```
NSString *s = [@"0800 444 333" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  Remove  white Space in Your Phone Contact Eg "+92 3121245" like this 
+923121245.

Use following line of code

NSString telNum  =  @"+92 3121245";

NSString* cNum = [telNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" 
  withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code,

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"%20"];
```

or

```
str =  [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Answer (score -1):

NSString *Naveen = @"Naveen Kumar Singh";
NSString *secondString = [Naveen stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

Ans:-NaveenKumarSingh

Comment: Could you describe the difference to the accepted answer?